# Unhashable type list...what.... comparing values to keys

Tags: python

im about to finish up a project and this last part is getting me. Say i have the following code

```
t = {'CSE 2320' : ['lame']}
h = {'MATH': ['professional', 'CSE 2320', ['note: see approved list\n']]}
for keys in h :
    if h[keys] in t :
        print "its here"
```

why do i get that `unhashable type : 'list'`error? I just want to see if CSE 2320 is in t which it is. Whats the issue here/

Answer (score 0):

You are basically doing "if list in hash" which isn't allowed, you can only do "if element in hash".

```
for keys in h:
    for value in h[keys]:
        if value in t:
            print "it's here"
```

This will still need to guard against the nested list you have there, but should hopefully be enough to get you going again.

Comment: Actually OP only wants to "see if CSE 2320 is in t". So the correct answer should suggest `if keys[1] in t`, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over the items in the list returned by `h[key]`, as the last item in that list is also a list(`['note: see approved list\n']`), so you need to handle such items as well. :

```
t = {'CSE 2320' : ['lame']}
h = {'MATH': ['professional', 'CSE 2320', ['note: see approved list\n']]}
for keys in h :
    if any(k in t for k in h[keys] if not isinstance(k, list)):
            print "its here"
```